# How to add numbers from text files

Tags: python, text-files

I have two text files. One is called 'RoundOneWinners' and looks like this:

```
C,18
D,22
F,25
E,26
```

The other one is called 'RoundTwoTotalScores_entered' and looks like this:

```
C, 9
D, 15
F, 21
E, 27
```

What I need to do is add the corresponding letters in each text file and then save them into a new text file. 
The future text file should look like this:

```
C, 27
D, 37
F, 46
E, 53
```

^ These are made by adding together C and C from the two text files etc.

The question is, what code would i use to open up both of the text files, be able to get the code out and then add them together. I'm sorry i don't have any example code, i have no clue where to start as i am very new at this

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: What is your question? SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: I have just added the question at the end, sorry

Comment: And  i have tried some stuff already but nothing worth posting as it all failed miserably and i have no idea where to start

Comment: I woul look into `numpy.loadtxt()`.

Comment: Here is a [Try it online](https://tio.run/##ZZDJasMwEIbveoqBHmKDKFiQbpBTl2MLbaCHEIqpx8lQZyS0OJjSZ3dHjkMP1UUM8/2L5Ia4t2zGkQ7O@ghhCGrnbXIBVvD9oz6T98hRhmfLqFrroSNGIM7oZYgN8Z0CAGphoRfANubdxAh7llOY9BMp5881g@LiyRXlvDzFb2Zme@ox6yxH4oR5/MJB93WXUIANcSz6Mpeg1aoC7AJCf/aF3Jp0n4shpwP6OmJxSnYdxUKKl@VW/c/eSEguMOUo5bzkzIxSF/LYI1BcBEgOooXBpnzVTSNFxSA4y/I9O6mDB7ELYFuIe5wdxvHVJm5eGN@JGX1Q97q6UQ/aGPWkzVI9anOlJmZ9tGsb6@5NfDF8iBd6bISHW@GhWooATCUKMNe/) that may help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Keep in mind, you will need to determine where your files are read from and written to.

```
import sys

f1d = {}
lines = open('/path/to/your/file1.csv')
for l in lines:
    sl = l.split(',')
    f1d[sl[0]] = int(sl[1])
lines.close()

f2d = {}
lines2 = open('/path/to/your/file2.csv')
for l in lines2:
    sl = l.split(',')
    f2d[sl[0]] = int(sl[1])
lines2.close()

output = ''
for k,v in f1d.iteritems():
    output += k + ',' + str(f1d[k] + f2d[k]) + '\n'

f = open('/path/to/your/file.csv', 'w')
f.write(output)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer:

```
# assuming the order of the results is important, we us an OrderedDict
from collections import OrderedDict
totals = OrderedDict()

# open the file
with open('RoundOneWinners.txt','r') as f:
    # loop over the rows
    for row in f:
        # split the row into letter and number
        letter, number = row.split(',')

        # try to add the number to the entry in totals.
        try:
            totals[letter] += int(number)
        except KeyError:
            # we could not find the letter in totals yet, so just set the value
            totals[letter] = int(number)

# same thing, second file
with open('RoundTwoTotalScores_entered.txt','r') as f:
    for row in f:
        letter, number = row.split(',')
        try:
            totals[letter] += int(number)
        except KeyError:
            totals[letter] = int(number)

# loop over your dictionary and write the results
with open('result.txt', "w") as f:
    for letter, total in totals.iteritems():
        f.write(",".join((letter, str(total))))
```